# {"username":["This field is required."]}

Tags: django, angular

Stuck with the error here. Works fine with the get request in angular but create problem while using post request. So guys help me. And thanks in advance guys.

**serializers.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers


class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """ Create and return a new user"""

        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        return user
```

**view.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import viewsets

from .serializers import UserSerializer


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """ API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited. """

    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
```

**register/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers

from . import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('users', views.UserViewSet)


# Wire up our API using automatic URL routing.
# Additionally, we include login URLs for the browsable API.

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

**django/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('register.urls')),
]
```

**error**

[image]

Comment: And what data are you sending? Does it include the username?

Comment: You should add your post data. Seems like you are not sending your username, which is mendatory in your serializer.

Comment: Thank you guys so much for your support. I will try your suggestion.